# Python: need to create a new column when merging multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

thanks for help in advance. multi-part question

I have zip files that has multiple stock pricing info.  the current format is 
Header row is:

```
ticker,date,open,high,low,close,vol
```

and first row example is

```
AAPL,201906030900,176.32,176.32,176.24,176.29,2247
```

---

desired format:

header

```
ticker,date,time,open,high,low,close,vol
```

---

and data

```
AAPL,20190603,09:00,176.32,176.32,176.24,176.29,2247
```

---

where the time column is added and the column is filled with the last 4 digits from the date row with a colon in the middle and those last 4 digits are removed from the date data column.

there about 400 rows of data for each stock in each file so each row would need to be converted.

i haven't been able to find an answer here or elsewhere on the web that i could understand how to accomplish what i am trying to do.

Comment: There is a lot of information in here, can you narrow it down somehow? _I have not been able to figure out how to insert the new column into the file with the format needed._ Can you be more specific? As for the second question, it's difficult to answer with so little information, but the simplest would probably be to modify each file before appending/concatenating.

Comment: AMC, thanks for looking at it.  i redid the question above to try to simplify and get answer to most pressing issue. if i can resolve this, I believe i can do or research for the other things i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, using `pandas`:
data.csv

```
ticker,date,open,high,low,close,vol
AAPL,201906030900,176.32,176.32,176.24,176.29,2247
ABCD,202002211000,220.97,217.38,221.43,219.82,8544
```

code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# print(df)

df['time'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: f'{str(x)[-4:-2]}:{str(x)[-2:]}')
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-4])

cols = df.columns.to_list()
cols = cols[:2] + cols[-1:] + cols[2:-1]

df = df[cols]

# print(df)

df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

output.csv

```
ticker,date,time,open,high,low,close,vol
AAPL,20190603,09:00,176.32,176.32,176.24,176.29,2247
ABCD,20200221,10:00,220.97,217.38,221.43,219.82,8544
```

You can use the same code to loop over multiple files.

Comment: thank you Young Wook..!!!  that is exactly what i needed.... i'm relatively new here, anything i can do in Stack Overflow to promote you or vote for you regarding your answer..